# using ZURB Foundation with laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, zurb-foundation

I am new to laravel so I am not sure how this can be achieved. I am using  ZURB Foundation and trying to create a button in the page.

I use `linkRoute` always to redirect to a named route then redirect to a specific controller action. I have the below:

```
<body >
    <h1 align="center">ShopCon.com</h1><br><br>
    <a style="margin-left:50px;" href="{{ HTML::linkRoute('membersaccess', 'Members Access') }}" class="medium success button">Login or Register</a>
</body>
```

but when I render this, it shows like this

```
Members Access" class="medium success button">Login or Register
```

instead of showing the button and text within it and link to named route. How can this be fixed? I read something about macros but unable to clearly understand them or use them to achieve this.

Picture included for reference:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HTML::linkRoute` produces an HTML anchor tag.

Since you only want the URL, use `URL::route`.